# Break large mathml content to fit in container width

Tags: html, css, svg, mathjax, mathml

I am using MathJax to convert mathml in svg. SVG used by some device which renders it.

html content

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  </style>
<script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
  </script>

</head>
<body>
 <math  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
  <mrow>
    <mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
    <msub><mi>m</mi><mn>1</mn></msub>
    <msubsup>
      <mi>u</mi>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msubsup>
  </mrow>
  <mo>+</mo>
  <mrow>
    <mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
    <msub><mi>m</mi><mn>2</mn></msub>
    <msubsup>
      <mi>u</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msubsup>
  </mrow>
  <mrow>
  <mtext>
  Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf 
  Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf  Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf Aasdf 
  </metxt>
  </mrow>
</math>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since MathJax renders the single mathml in single line only, in browser we can have scrollbar to view the complete mathml.
In my case device can not show scroll bar so it reduces the font size to display in the single line.

I know mathjax has some configuration by which we can control it .

```
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
                              CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
                              "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
                                     SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
                            });
```

This is not working for me.
How can we make Mathml responsive?

Can anyone suggest me how can i break long mathml to fit in container width.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MathJax's algorithm for line breaking is for breaking mathematics, not text.  So it does not break lines within a `<mtext>` element.  (MathJax does not break within any token element; it only breaks the mathematics at `<mo>` elements, when it can.)

It is not clear from your example how the long text within `<mtext>` is being used (since it is just fake text), but it looks like the text probably is part of a surrounding sentence, rather than the mathematics itself.  If so, you should not include that as part of the mathematics, but as text without the surrounding HTML.

Comment: MathJax alway adds height and width information to generated svg elements, height value it too small to fit the content in single line. How it actually calculate the height. BTW height and width unit is always in ex , does mathjax has any option to configure the generated unit.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment.  Increasing the height would make the line *wider*, so I don't see how it is too small.  The height and width are calculated to match the height of an "x" in the mathematics with the height of an "x" in the surrounding text.  That is one reason that it is given in units of "ex".  There is no mechanism to change that to other units.